# Refazer cache do Spring?

Tags: java, java-ee, spring

É possível agendar que o cache do Spring seja refeito sempre à meia-noite?

Eu li o [Springs Cache Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html&ei=mQb4BLm6) e não achei nada sobre como fazer ele ser regerado.

Comment: Acho que está procurando por isso [https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/]

Comment: A resposta te ajudou a resolver a dúvida? É possível aceitá-la agora?

Comment: Boa tarde, @Murilo, surgiram outras prioridades ao longo das semanas passada e retrasada. Estou voltando para esta solução agora e já respondo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algo que poderia ser feito é usar a expiração do cache (`@CacheEvict`) em conjunto com o agendamento (`Scheduled`), conforme abaixo:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
public class CachingConfig {
    public static final String GAMES = "GAMES";
    @Bean
    public CacheManager cacheManager() {
        ConcurrentMapCacheManager cacheManager = new ConcurrentMapCacheManager(GAMES);

        return cacheManager;
    }

    @CacheEvict(allEntries = true, value = {GAMES})
    @Scheduled(cron = "* * 0 * * ?")
    public void reportCacheEvict() {
        System.out.println("Flush Cache " + dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

Baseado [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38261593/5230740).